# Get approval status in GitHub action

Tags: github-actions

I have an action that fires when a label is added.

`pull_request: types: [labeled]`

The job should run conditionally, only if the pull-request is approved (there is one or more approval) as well as another condition which is working fine:

```
jobs:
  build:
    if: ${{ (something == 'approved') && (contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'Deployed for QA')) }}
```

What property can I use in place of 'something' in the condition above?

Answer (score 10):

> You can use if: `github.event.review.state == 'approved'` along with
> your other condition.

Actually, this suggestion from **LeadingMoominExpert** is part of a possible solution.

##### Tests

I tried this implementation using the `pull_request: types: [labeled]` as suggested on the question from **Dan Cook** and it wasn't working.

The problem is because the pull_request **labeled** event doesn't have the `github.event.review.state` field filled on the $GITHUB_CONTEXT when this event occurs, therefore the value will be **null** and the condition will return `false`.

To make it works, I had to change the workflow trigger `on` condition to `pull_request_review: types: [submitted]` instead of `pull_request: types: [labeled]`.

But the behavior isn't exactly the same as expected.

In that case, the event will trigger only when someone submit a review, and if the pull request state is approved, and already has the expected label, then the workflow's job will be executed.

##### To check the behavior of each event you can try this implementation

```yaml
name: PR approved and labeled

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled]
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ (github.event.review.state == 'approved') && (contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'test')) }}
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
      - run: echo ${{ github.event.review.state }}
```

You'll see that adding a **label** (in that case, containing `test`) won't execute the job, but **submitting a review approving this PR**, with the expected label set, will run it.

##### Conclusion

**Dan**, what you want to achieve isn't possible (yet?) using the `pull_request: types: [labeled]` event.

The example above is a workaround, but that may not attend exactly what you expect.

Comment: looks like this is the best we can achieve, even though it doesn't solve the real issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'`
along with your other condition.